# Socky Alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket

I'm in search of a RELIABLE websocket server for ROR 3.Now we're using [socky](https://github.com/socky). It is unreliable. We like it because it has flash fallback, so it suppose to work on older browsers...but again -  it is unreliable. 
Do you know any good websocket server for ROR with fallback (i.e. supporting all browsers)

Comment: we use faye / socket.io in production and testing juggernaut at the moment.

Comment: @sled, How does it perform? hard to setup? Does it have a fallback?

Comment: @sled Make your comment an answer. If you'd consider a hosted service then you might find [Pusher](http://pusher.com), who I work for, an interesting solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

alternatives are:

- [socket.io](http://www.socket.io) (raw Websocket for NodeJS)
- [juggernaut](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) (Complete Bayeux Protocol for NodeJS/Rails)
- [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) (Complete Bayeux Protocol for NodeJS/Rails) with a Ruby-Server

A tip: don't use ruby as websocket server, go for NodeJS - we handle thousands of messages every hour without any issue.

We used the most simple setup possible to make it work - and it works ;)

Our Setup:

- Rails 3.0.9
- Redis
- NodeJS
- Socket.IO

How we set it up:

```
Rails --PUB--> REDIS --SUB--> NodeJS --WEBSOCKET (SOCKET.IO)--> Client
```

Article [Redis PubSub - How does it work?](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/6325247416/redis-pub-sub-how-does-it-work)

Another tip: Avoid authentication if possible

Here's our case:

We have something like a project management tool with a virtual filesystem. Let's say you're viewing a folder while someone else of your team uploads a new file. Now we have to inform you that your view is out of the date - we send a message like:

`folder_id | last_change_timestamp`

to the channel `folders:#{folder_id}`

now the client (which listens to `folders:#{folder_id}` receives that messages and sees "whoops my view is out of date" and shows a message "Your view is outdated, please click >here< to refresh".

The good thing is that we don't need any authentication because:

1. if you have no access to the project you would have to guess the folder_id to subscribe to the channel
2. even if you manage to subscribe to the channel the only information you get is that something has changed - not more not less ;)